# I'm unable to authenticate with Github when trying to push code

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push code to Github but I keep getting an error.  My understanding is that I should use a blank username and my PAT as the password.  However, I get the error in the screenshot (sorry I had to blank out so much).  This PAT has full admin privileges to the organization and is currently used inside of code to perform administrative tasks, and performing the login is to use a blank username and the PAT as the password; we use this login to execute API calls.  Can I get some assistance as to what I need to do here?  Also it appears that it's using Windows credentials manager, but the credentials are not present there.  Windows prompts for the username and password.

[image]

Comment: Looks like in your screenshot as if you are pushing to gitlab.com and not github.com. Those are different services that will use different authentication credentials.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I mean to delete this.  You're correct, we are pushing to gitlab but the PAT they generated for us was for Github, because the people we are working with didn't know the difference.  Once I found out what was happening we got it resolved immediately, thank you so much for your help on this.